# Odd result in pgfplots when scale and set layers is used together

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem when I use `scale` and `set layers` in pgfplots.

I have to use `set layers` because I want that several curves in one plot are above each other (that is not really visible in my example code below) and I want to use scale to make the plot and the labelling smaller. 
If you run my example code, you can see from the first figure that everything is fine if one uses `set layers` and `scale=1`. If one uses `scale=0.8` without `set layers`, everything works as expected (second figure; in my real plot the curves are not above each other anymore).
But if one uses `scale=0.8` and `set layers`, an odd result is produced. The plot is smaller, but not the labelling. Also the legend is at wrong position.

Who can tell me what I do wrong? I really have to use `set layers` together with `scale` so that my real plot looks fine.

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{filecontents}{TableQuestion.txt}
xValue1 yValue1     xValue2 yValue2 
1   0     1   0.2
2   1        2   0.9
3   1.5   3   1.6
4   0.5   4   0.4 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]%everything ok
\begin{axis}[
set layers,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,legend pos=north west,legend cell align=left]%
\addplot[color=blue,
mark=*,mark layer=like plot]%
table[x=xValue1,y=yValue1] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\addplot[color=red,
mark=none]%
table[x=xValue2,y=yValue2] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\legend{first entry, second entry}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]%everything ok
\begin{axis}[
%set layers,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,legend pos=north west,legend cell align=left]%
\addplot[color=blue,
mark=*,mark layer=like plot]%
table[x=xValue1,y=yValue1] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\addplot[color=red,
mark=none]%
table[x=xValue2,y=yValue2] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\legend{first entry, second entry}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]%odd behaviour
\begin{axis}[
set layers, 
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,legend pos=north west,legend cell align=left]%
\addplot[color=blue,
mark=*,mark layer=like plot]%
table[x=xValue1,y=yValue1] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\addplot[color=red,
mark=none]%
table[x=xValue2,y=yValue2] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\legend{first entry, second entry}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a feeling we've had a similar question before. I can't find it though.

Comment: Before I ask a question I always check if there are similar questions. Perhaps I overlooked the question you mean. I am not sure.

Comment: Well, I can't find the similar question I thought there was, so maybe I dreamed it.

Comment: Haha, perhaps you can dream of a solution too and post it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a bug in pgfplots.

A work-around for this particular example could be to draw the tikzpicture *without* a scale and scale the complete tikzpicture afterwards. That could be a scalebox or tikzpicture with `transform shape`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.8]%odd behaviour
\node {%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
set layers, 
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,legend pos=north west,legend cell align=left]%
\addplot[color=blue,
mark=*,mark layer=like plot]%
table[x=xValue1,y=yValue1] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\addplot[color=red,
mark=none]%
table[x=xValue2,y=yValue2] {TableQuestion.txt};%
\legend{first entry, second entry}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: I fear you are right and this is a bug in pgfplots – but only a little bug in a wonderful package!
Your workaround works perfectly – thanks for posting it!